# Rhinomocks, has anybody used and good resource for it

Tags: resources, rhino-mocks

We are developing our new application in .Net 3.5 and we have started using Rhinomock.
I know it's used for mocking but I don't have good resource for it.

Can anyone suggest me any good resource/link/tutorial for the it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Rhino Mocks offers a lot of features where a lot of them exist for backwards compatibility. For that reason, there are confusingly many ways to achieve a desired result. Don't get me wrong: Rhino Mocks is good, but for an alternative with a cleaner API, take a look at Moq (http://code.google.com/p/moq/) - you may find it has a gentler learning curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RhinoMocks wiki is decent for some starter knowledge: [RhinoMocks wiki](http://ayende.com/Wiki/(S(cvnxfa55ptgclrq2f0yqkd45))/Rhino+Mocks.ashx)